# Silent Signin feature not working using Casdoor

Tags: reactjs, node.js, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm working on a solution to seamlessly login the users into all my applications and we chose Casdoor for this purpose. I've tried oAuth2 and when I try to login my first app, it works like a charm but when I try to access the second app using query param `?silentSignin=1` then it generates an hidden Iframe and tries to authenticate in the background. But the problem I'm facing is the Iframe cannot access/detect my Casdoor session because Casdoor is hosted on another domain `https://casdoor.local` and my both apps are hosted on separate domains each. `https://appone.local` and `https://apptwo.local`.

It blocks the cookies because of cross site and when I inspect the network tab and see the requests then I can see the blocked response cookies and Casdoor session cookie cannot be set because of `SameSite=lax` by default and to set the cookie it should be `SameSite=None`. But Casdoor is not using that in response header, so the question is how can I have the silent signin working?

BTW, I'm using the [casdoor-react-sdk](https://github.com/casdoor/casdoor-react-sdk) and using 2 instances of Casdoor react examples: https://github.com/casdoor/casdoor-nodejs-react-example

If you need to look into code, you can do so by checking this example as I'm using the same example just for testing the silent signin.

**EDIT:**
Here's the get app login request which is failing to set the cookie
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not cross-site. Casdoor only uses its own domain and doesn't need to access application's domain.

The problem is that you need to turn on two options in your Casdoor's application edit page.

1. `Signin session` means Casdoor will remember the cookie when someone logged in via OAuth.
2. `Auto signin` means Casdoor will automatically login and redirect when it found the above cookie exists.

After setting these, the hidden iframe can silently finish the login process and notify your application. Then your application refreshes itself and show the logged-in status like an account profile avatar.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it still not work though? Since we are trying to send the Casdoor cookie session from inside the application using an IFrame (Cross domain Third-party cookie)? I would expect this to work only with normal full redirect, or am i missing something here?

Comment: @hsluoyz Thanks for the response. But I already have both of these options enabled in both my apps, but still it's not working.